# Python: change parent class property from child class

Tags: python, class, syntax

In python (v3.6.1), I am looking to write a class like this:

```
class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    property = "custom"

print(SecondClass.name) #=> "john"

class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    property = "notcustom"

print(SecondClass.name) #=> "steve"
```

I have tried to set up the `FirstClass` class like this:

```
class FirstClass:
    if property == "custom":
        name = "john"
    else:
        name = "steve"
```

But I don't seem to be able to edit the property of the `FirstClass` from the SecondClass.

Is this possible?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I've added the version into the question (it's 3.6.1)

Comment: `init` and `self` sections is missing, please open any python module for syntax, will be guide you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3.6, you can accomplish what your asking by using the new [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method. From the documentation on `__init_subclass__`:

> This method is called whenever the containing class is subclassed. cls is then the new subclass. If defined as a normal instance method, this method is implicitly converted to a class method.

```
class FirstClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        if cls.property == "custom":
            cls.name = "john"
        else:
            cls.name = "steve"

class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    property = "custom"

print(SecondClass.name)

class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    property = "notcustom"

print(SecondClass.name)
```

For a method that works with Python 3.5  and lower, you can use some Meta class magic:

```
class FirstClass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if cls.property == "custom":
            cls.name = "john"
        else:
            cls.name = "steve"
        super(FirstClass, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

class SecondClass(metaclass=FirstClass):
    property = "custom"

print(SecondClass.name)

class SecondClass(metaclass=FirstClass):
    property = "notcustom"

print(SecondClass.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

`@classmethod` might be your best bet here.

```
class First:
    @classmethod
    def name(cls):
        return "john" if cls.prop() == "custom" else "steve"

class Second(First):
    @classmethod
    def prop(cls):
        return "custom"

print(Second.name()) # -> john

class Second(First):
    @classmethod
    def prop(cls):
        return "notcustom"

print(Second.name()) # -> steve
```

(also, don't use `property` because that's already a keyword in the language

Comment: +1 for the pointers and the note on `property` being a keyword in python, but @Christian Dean's answer was exactly what I was after